# Visualising the distribution for different subgroups

Tags: r, density-plot, ecdf

I'm using "d.pizza" data. There is variable called "delivery_min" which is delivery time (in minutes) and there is variable called "area" which can be one of three areas (Camden, Westminster and Brent).
I want to draw a density plot that visualises **the distribution** of delivery time for these three areas.

I tried

```
 plot.ecdf(pizza_d$delivery_min)
```

this code works, but how can I do it for each area?

```
head(d.pizza)=

index       date week weekday        area count rabate  price operator  driver delivery_min
1 1     1 01.03.2014    9       6      Camden     5   TRUE 65.655   Rhonda  Taylor         20.0
2 2     2 01.03.2014    9       6 Westminster     2  FALSE 26.980   Rhonda Butcher         19.6
3 3     3 01.03.2014    9       6 Westminster     3  FALSE 40.970  Allanah Butcher         17.8
4 4     4 01.03.2014    9       6       Brent     2  FALSE 25.980  Allanah  Taylor         37.3
5 5     5 01.03.2014    9       6       Brent     5   TRUE 57.555   Rhonda  Carter         21.8
6 6     6 01.03.2014    9       6      Camden     1  FALSE 13.990  Allanah  Taylor         48.7
  temperature wine_ordered wine_delivered wrongpizza quality
1        53.0            0              0      FALSE  medium
2        56.4            0              0      FALSE    high
3        36.5            0              0      FALSE    <NA>
4          NA            0              0      FALSE    <NA>
5        50.0            0              0      FALSE  medium
6        27.0            0              0      FALSE     low
```

Comment: Hi, please take a look at [how to make a reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).  Knowing your dataset's name and columns is helpful, but in order to provide a complete answer we'll need more than that.  About the best I can do at the moment is suggest that you `filter` your dataset by your areas and plot those individually

Comment: @Punintended, i don't know how to filter my data to have only delivery times for "Brent" area (for example)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do:

```r
library(DescTools)

data(d.pizza)

plot.ecdf(subset(d.pizza, area == "Camden")$delivery_min, 
          col = "red", main = "ECDF for pizza deliveries")
plot.ecdf(subset(d.pizza, area == "Westminster")$delivery_min, 
          add = TRUE, col = "blue")
plot.ecdf(subset(d.pizza, area == "Brent")$delivery_min, 
          add = TRUE, col = "green")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

```
library(DescTools)

data(d.pizza)
summary(d.pizza$delivery_min)

plot(NULL,ylab='',xlab='', xlim=c(5,66), ylim=0:1)
for(A in 1:3) {
    plot.ecdf(d.pizza$delivery_min[d.pizza$area == levels(d.pizza$area)[A]], 
        pch=20, col=A+1, add=T)
}
legend("bottomright", legend=levels(d.pizza$area), 
        bty='n', pch=20, col=2:4)
```

[image: ECDF by area]

Comment: sorry, but I meant the distribution plot for these three areas (distribution function), sorry for mistake.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend the ggplot2 library for data visualization in R. Here's some code using ggplot2 that can create a density plot with the three groups overlaid:

```
library(ggplot2)

# make example dataframe
d.pizza <- data.frame(delivery_min = rnorm(n=30), area = rep(c("Camden", "Westminster", "Brent"), 10))

# plot data in ggplot2
ggplot(d.pizza, aes(x = delivery_min, fill = area, color = area)) + geom_density(alpha = 0.5)
```

[image]

If you want a histogram, that can be done too:

```
ggplot(d.pizza, aes(x = delivery_min, fill = area, color = area)) + geom_histogram(alpha = 0.5, position = 'identity')
```

Comment: I think that you got the density function,  not the _cumulative_ density function.